# After Chrome's latest update, the background css I use no longer works

Tags: css, google-chrome

Below is the line the chrome debugger is complaining about, it says it is invalid. This line worked before the update and more of my users are starting to have the same problem as they update their browsers.

```css
background: url(https://www.playinitium.com/images/banner---town.jpg) 50% 50% / contain no-repeat rgb(30, 43, 83), rgb(30, 43, 83);
```

The version of Chrome that doesn't like this line is: Version 46.0.2490.71 m

Does anyone know of any spec changes that would not allow this background CSS line to work?

**EDIT**

I realized later that the way chrome represents the background CSS is different than the way I set it. Here is how it is set:

```
background: url('images/effects/light-rain1.gif') no-repeat center center, url('"+bannerUrl+"') no-repeat center center, rgba("+r+", "+g+", "+b+", "+amount+")

        background-blend-mode: screen, multiply
        background-size: contain,contain,contain
```

I have 2 computers, on the one with the latest Chrome it doesn't appear to be blending, the one with a slightly earlier version of chrome it is.

It might also be pertinent to know that I dynamically set this using jQuery.

**Edit 2**

I just compared the versions between the two Chromes (between the one that works and the one that doesn't) and they are the same! The only difference is the one that started failing started immediately after updating my chrome.

So very strange.

Comment: Protip: try validating your code before blaming your browser.

Comment: @cimmanon: "But it works in Chrome, so it must be valid!"

Comment: @cimmanon My apologies. I didn't realize chrome was showing me a different background CSS value than the one I had set. I updated my question!

Comment: Well, this changes everything. I still don't see how the way you have set it in your script could possibly be represented the way Chrome is representing it.

Comment: @BoldClock I know right? I think jQuery does do some "magic" under the hood when it is interpreting certain values.. maybe it has something to do with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this really is a Chrome bug. Others have started to report the issue here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543583

Answer (score 2):

You have two background-color values:

```
... no-repeat rgb(30, 43, 83), rgb(30, 43, 83);
```

That has never been valid CSS, since [you may only have one color layer and it must be declared last](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background). This has not changed in [a decade](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-background-20050216/#the-background), but I can't say I'm surprised to learn that Chrome has nevertheless been accepting it this whole time.

To fix, remove one of the `rgb(30, 43, 83)` values:

```
... no-repeat, rgb(30, 43, 83);
```

and preferably the comma as well:

```
... no-repeat rgb(30, 43, 83);
```

The declaration is valid with one color value, with or without the comma, but it has subtly different meanings with basically the same end result. Generally if you only have one background image, you put the color with the image in the same layer. This will improve compatibility with browsers that don't support layered backgrounds, which you're not really trying to achieve anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp)

> CSS3 Multiple Backgrounds
>
> CSS3 allows you to add multiple background
>   images for an element, through the background-image property.
>
> The different background images are separated by commas, and the
>   images are stacked on top of each other, where the first image is
>   closest to the viewer.

However, you have an invalid background property. Chrome might fix this bug. You can solve the problem by removing the second background value.

```
background: url(https://www.playinitium.com/images/banner---town.jpg) 50% 50% / contain no-repeat rgb(30, 43, 83);
```